# Is it ethical to place Company projects in CV.?

Tags: resume

I want to place some of the projects I did in my company as an Associate Software Engineer in CV. There are two kinds of a project I got involved with.

1. Projects where a number of developers got involved.
2. Projects where I was the sole developer, but there were managers and a tech lead.

Is it ethical to place such projects in CVs without mentioning anything about technical or business matters while briefly explaining my role on the project.? Specifically, I'm concerned about exposing any business related information my current employer might consider as private (those are not very unique projects).

Eg:- 
**Developed a Beverage Manufacturing project for - XYZ, inc**

Scope of work:- Business Analysis and System Analysis

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- what do you see as the ethical problem here? Not properly crediting others?

Comment: Thank you, question updated to include, why I "feel" this can be seen as a violation of ethics.

Comment: If there's a problem, it would probably be a legal one, e.g. you sign an NDA and you're discussing something which violates that. If it's just a matter of respecting the company's private information, we have no way to know whether it would be considered as such for your scenario, and ultimately, if you didn't get any input from the company regarding this, you'll need to decide by yourself whether or not any given piece of information is sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ethical to place such projects in CVs without mentioning anything about technical or business matters?

Well, as those were projects you were involved, and some of them even solely developed by you it is ok to include them in your CVs.

However, it is *not ok* to include them without mentioning for whom or under what company you made them, as this will suggest that you alone owned and developed all those projects.

You could try listing those projects in your CV by referencing to the job or company you were working for when developing them. Make sure to check with your employer which projects it is ok to list on your CV, as other agreements may be in place that you are not aware of (as @HorusKol suggests). Something like:

> Sept, 2010 - Sept, 2016; Senior Developer on Foo Inc. Projects involved with:
>
> 1. Developed a Beverage Manufacturing project Scope of work:- Business Analysis and System Analysis
>
> ...

Comment: Should add the caveat that some projects may be under a non-disclosure type arrangement between the OPs employer and client - listing those may breach the NDA. It may be possible to list them without disclosing the relationship, but sometimes it isn't (like "national census website for major government department" makes it pretty obvious). OP could maybe still include "major government projects", though.

Comment: @HorusKol you are right, the OP should also ask to the employee which projects it is ok to list on his CV. Editing the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is depends on the agreement with your current employer.

In my current company,

I have no permission to tell any details about my projects (even the project name or client name) to any one without permission.